# Delay in thread allocation with ExecutorService

Tags: java, asynchronous, openshift, latency, threadpoolexecutor

We have been noticing intermittent latency issues when there is a burst of traffic (~60-80 tps) for one of the flows within our application. In each occurrence of the increased response time, it has been observed that the maximum amount of time is being taken while allocating a new thread to start an async task.

*Application Details*:
**Java version**: 8, **Web server**: JBoss, **Framework**: SpringBoot, **Deployment**: On-Premise cloud (Openshift)

*ExecutorService* configuration:

`private final ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 30, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());`

Code snippet below - *mainMethod* invokes *methodOne* and *methodTwo* using async process but the time taken between entering methodOne and methodTwo clearly shows significant delay under high load.

```
public void mainMethod() {
    log.info("inside methodOne()"); // for eg. 9:10:00 UTC
    CompletableFuture<someObj> completableFuture = AsyncUtil.supply(
            () -> methodTwo(), executorService);

public void methodOne() {
    log.info("inside methodOne()"); // for eg. 9:10:05 UTC

public void methodTwo() {
    log.info("inside methodTwo()"); // for eg. 9:10:07 UTC

CompletableFuture.allOf(methodOne, methodTwo).get();
```

As seen above, we have a core thread pool size of 3 with maximum thread count of 30. This application is deployed on 8 pods in the production environment.

1. As part of our investigation, we collected thread dumps during peak hours.
2. We have also verified the logs collected from Splunk and DynaTrace. Attaching DynaTrace view for reference which indicates that maximum time is taken waiting for thread allocation.[Dynatrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvLSv.png)
3. The pods have been restarted but the behavior is still the same.
4. Both show a common pattern - on each pod, for each request that shows increased latency, JVM is waiting to **allocate a new thread to the async task from within the core pool only (3)**.
5. The logs indicate that the async task is executing only from *pool17*: thread 1, 2, 3; even though the maximum pool size is 30.

Attaching the Splunk logs below for reference:

> 10/6/23 **10:14:25.689** **PM**
> [0m22:14:25,689 INFO  [stdout] (Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLoggerConfig-1) INFO  [**default task-1073**]: 2023-10-06T22:14:25,689 - requestTime=2023-10-06T22:14:24.537-0700
> Entering method *mainMethod* ...
>
> 10/6/23 **10:14:30.748 PM**
> [0m22:14:30,748 INFO  [stdout] (Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLoggerConfig-1) INFO  [**pool-17-thread-3**]: 2023-10-06T22:14:30,748 - requestTime=2023-10-06T22:14:24.537-0700
> Entering method *methodOne* of ...
>
> 10/6/23 **10:14:31.509 PM**
> [0m22:14:31,509 INFO  [stdout] (Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLoggerConfig-1) INFO  [**pool-17-thread-2**]: 2023-10-06T22:14:31,509 - requestTime=2023-10-06T22:14:24.537-0700
> Entering method *methodTwo* of ...

As seen above, there is a 5 second delay between first and second logger statements. As per our assumption, this is the wait time to allocate the thread to the async task. We have also highlighted the pool# and thread# being allocated to the tasks.

Another thing to note based on the logs, the async task is always using *pool17* on all the 8 pods.

Few questions:

1. Even though the logs indicate pool17 on all the pods, our assumption is that each pod maintains its own thread pool of objects. Is that understanding correct?
2. Though *ExecutorService* maximum pool size is 30, logs always indicate that async tasks are always using thread 1, thread 2, thread 3; which is the core pool size. Why is the async task not leveraging other thread outside of the core pool.
3. Each pod size is *1 CPU x 4 GB RAM*. Based on the pod configuration, should we tweak the ExecutorService configuration.

Comment: From [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html): "_When a new task is submitted in method execute(Runnable), if fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle. Else if fewer than maximumPoolSize threads are running, a new thread will be created to handle the request **only if the queue is full**_".

Comment: You're using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` with a capacity of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so it is highly unlikely that the queue will ever become full.

Comment: Thank you @Slaw! So basically, creating an unbounded queue is resulting in no threads being allocated from outside the core pool, rendering the max pool size useless. There is no mention as to what should be the optimum value though. It is understood that these values are dependent upon each application (throughput requirements, load, etc.) but is it suggested that we keep max core pool size at 30 with _SynchronousQueue_ given our peak load could be 40-50 tps?

Comment: Does "tps" stand for "tasks per second"? Because if yes, then using `SynchronousQueue` with a relatively small number of maximum threads is likely to result in a `RejectedExecutionException`. At least with the default `RejectedExecutionHandler`; perhaps you're okay with using [`CallerRunsPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html). Maybe you should consider setting the core thread count higher and possibly letting core threads die.

Comment: In short, I would suggest profiling your application, during both normal operation and peak operation, and tune values such as the core thread count, maximum thread count, queue capacity, keep alive time, whether to let core threads die, and rejection policy until you get what you consider optimal behavior.

Comment: By tps, I am referring to 'transactions per second'. But I get your point. We are currently testing the performance of the application in lower environment, by tweaking thread pool size (core and max) and queue type, to find the right balance that works for us.

Comment: Hi @MohitAgarwal, we are facing a similar issue in our application. can you let us know what was the best combination based on your testing? We tried to use core/maximum queues with the same value with a LinkedBlockingQueue

Comment: @wassim sorry but we couldn’t come to a conclusion, due to limitations of the lower environment to carry heavy loads for issue replication. We did resolve the issue by terminating the connections that exceeded the platform threshold limits. And once the platform got stabilized, the project priorities changed as expected.